# netbeans 7.2 gives option to run but not to deploy

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, netbeans-7, restlet-2.0

I have create a webservice in netbeans. When I right-click on the project, I see the `run` option but not the `deploy` option. When I pick up a simple `Hello World` example on the Restlet website, theirs shows both `deploy` and `run` options. The difference between mine and theirs is that mine is using hibernate and mysql.

Does anyone know in general why netbeans may show the `run` option but not the `deploy` option for a web service project? I am using Glassfish

Answer (score 0):

Is the web application you created a maven web application? If so, that's probably why it doesn't have a "deploy" option, because maven would take care that for you.